# Java: Accessing pointers

Tags: java, pointers

I get: 'unexpected type
    required: variable
    found   : value'  on the marked lines (*)

```
for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
        rows[i].getSquare(j) = matrix[i][j]; // * points to the ( in (j)
        columns[j].getSquare(i) = matrix[i][j]; // * points to the ( in
        int[] b = getBox(i, j);
        int[] boxCord = getBoxCoordinates(i + 1, j + 1);
        boxes[b[0]][b[1]].getSquare(boxCord[0], boxCord[1]);
    }
}
```

This is my Row class:

```
private Square[] row;

Row(int rowCount) {
    this.row = new Square[rowCount];
}

public Square getSquare(int index) {
    return this.row[index];
}
```

Please help me out by pointing out what I'm doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some good answers on your previous questions, you really should accept some of them

Answer (score 10):

You cannot assign something to the return value of a method. Instead, you need to add a `setSquare()` method to the `Row` class:

```
public Square setSquare(int index, Square value) {
    this.row[index] = value;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
rows[i].setSquare(j, matrix[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have pointers - references are not the same thing.

It's impossible to tell what's really going on based on the code you posted.  I think you need a method to set the value of that Square in the private array your Row class owns.

```
public void setSquare(int index, Square newSquare) {
    this.row[index] = newSquare; 
}
```

It looks like a poor abstraction, in any case.

Answer (score -2):

Java has no pointers. Objects are passed and returned by reference. In terms of C++, `rows[i].getSquare(j)` is an **rvalue**, not an **lvalue**, so you cannot assign to it.

Instead, you should create and use `rows[i].setSquare(...)`.

Comment: Objects aren't passed by reference. References are passed by value.

Comment: The "pass by reference" thing is flaky. But on the other hand the lvalue/rvalue stuff is right.

Comment: Right you are, sorry for the awkward phrasing.

Comment: See my answer for further explanation on how Java passes references by  value: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657