# Arrays and passing by reference

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

In the following code, why is arr2[0] still equal to 1.5 even though the original array is changed in method2? Ignore the other arrays and variables.

```
public class Problem3
{
    public static int method1(int[] array)
    {
        array[0] += 10;
        return array[0];
    }

    public static int method2(int aNum, String aStr,
        int[] array1, float[] array2, int[] array3)
    {
        float[] fNums = {1.5F, 2.5F};
        array2 = fNums;

        return 10 + method1(array3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num = 1000;
        String aStr = "Hello!";
        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
        float[] arr2 = {0.5F, 1.5F};
        int[] arr3 = {5, 6, 7};
        int retNum = method2(num, aStr, arr1, arr2, arr3);

        System.out.println(arr2[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically I thought the answer was 1.5 but the solution says 0.5 and I'm wondering if someone could explain?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657

Comment: there is no pass by reference in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, because `array2` is not `arr2`, but they refer to the same array in memory on calling `method2`:

```
method2(num, aStr, arr1, arr2, arr3);
```

```
public static int method2(int aNum, String aStr, int[] array1, float[] array2, int[] array3)
```

Then, you make `array2` refers to a new array which `fNums` is referring to, and you didn't change the array that `arr2` referes to:

```
float[] fNums = {1.5F, 2.5F};
array2 = fNums;
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

because you changed the reference to the entire array and did not modify the array passed in.

When you call method2 the argument points to the array created outside. In the method2 you make the argument point to a new array.  this does not alter the array which the variable in the calling method is pointing to, that is still pointing to the original array.

If you simply modified the existing array you were given in method2, then you would see those changes in the calling method.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Java uses pass-by-value paramter passing semantics.  By declaring `float[] arr2` within PSVM(), its scope is limited to there, and if you pass the array to another function, it gets passed by value.

If, on the other hand, you had declared `float[] arr2` *outside* of PSVM() (but within the class definition), then its scope would be global within the class.  However, I still don't think your code would work, because IIRC, you cannot assign the value of an entire array with a single assignment like your code does in `method2()`.