# How is Java able to pass out parameter from method

Tags: java, android

I came across something that I could not comprehend and never realized it could be done.

I was playing around with this block of code in Android, and what intrigued me was this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    Rect outRect = new Rect();
    _btn.getHitRect(outRect);
    // ... rest of code cut
    // outRect fields of that Rect object is 'filled' in.
}
```

How is it that Android's Java can directly modify a `Rect` object `outRect` which was passed into the method in order to obtain the `Rect` of a button widget.

That surprised me, as I thought there was no such thing as '*pass by reference*' in Java, in Java parlance, using a '*call-by-reference*' rather, its '*pass by value*' or '*call-by-value*'?

Yes, I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) asked before but am stumped, or is that an Android thing?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I added an image, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers - much appreciated now that it makes sense! :) +1 to all of you from me :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404625/java-pass-by-reference/9404727#9404727

Comment: @Eng.Fouad bloody 'ell... brilliant - +1 from me :)

Comment: btw @Eng.Fouad that's favourited now, so that I can pass on that linky to someone who ends up like what I had to do... :)

Comment: @t0mm13b I am glad to know that my answer is being helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `outRect` reference is passed to the `getHitRect` method, which then modifies the object referred to by `outRect`. References are passed by value.

For a detailed explanation of this, read this article: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: That's a bit confusing - you say "References are passed by value", in other words a copy? (Good linky by the way - bookmarked - cheers mate)

Comment: The reference (address) itself is a copy, and as such, it's still the same address. So it points to the same object.

Comment: @t0mm13b That's right! The name "`outRect`" is really the name of a reference to an object. That reference is passed by value (i.e., copied in) to the `getHitRect` method, which then has its own reference to the same object referred to by `outRect`. The important thing to note is that the OBJECT referred to by `outRect` is not being passed, but only a reference to it.

Comment: @MikeDaniels Gotcha! Yes, you emphasized the keyword **OBJECT** - that's important... :) Makes sense now!

Answer (score 4):

The address, in the case of the objects, is a value, the value is copied, analogous to the primitive values. But it's a value which points to an object, and the object is not copied. It exists only once in memory and can be manipulated.[image]

Comment: This is incorrect; objects are *not* passed.  References are passed, and the mechanism is by value.  It's more than semantics.

Comment: That's what I mean, only expressed it incorrectly, will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to the Rect object is passed by value but the Rect object itself is allocated on the heap so it can be updated. In effect, this gives you pass-by-reference semantics. However, you cannot change the reference; in other words, something like this won't work:

```
public void someFunction(Rect r) {
  r = new Rect(); // will not be seen by the calling function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The highest-rated answer to the question you linked to explains this pretty clearly:

> Java is always pass-by-value. The difficult thing can be to understand that Java passes objects as references passed by value.

It then goes on to show two examples that leave no mystery in the behavior you're asking about, unless I've misunderstood what's surprised you.

Comment: Coming from a C/C++ background - that's what surprised me :D but yeah +1 from me even though I read that linked question which kind of left me floundering a bit. :)

Answer (score 1):

All parameters to methods in Java are passed by value, both primitives and objects. However, the way objects are referenced in Java is closer to that a C++ pointer than a value. For instance, consider that any object value in Java may take the value `null`, but in C++ only pointers make take the value `null` (whereas objects and references* are always valid initialised values).

But what does pass-by-value for an object value actually mean? It means to create a copy of an object and push it onto the stack for the called method to use. Whereas for a pointer it means to push the pointer value onto the stack. That way both the calling and the called method have access to the same memory location where the object value is stored. Thus any changes performed in the called method will be reflected in the calling method.

* There are some instances where a reference may contain corrupt data.