# pass by reference/value - simple example

Tags: java

I know this issue has been addressed many times - but my Java/C++ knowledge is so weak I can barely understand the answers :-( ... what I'd really like is just a super simple example.

In C++ I could write the following:

```
void func()
{
  int x = 3;
  add_one(x);
  // now x is 4.
}
void add_one(int &var)
{
  var++;
}
```

What I'd like to see now is the simplest way to achieve the same effect with java.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't directly.  The closest you can get is to put the value in an object, and pass the reference (by value, so the reference gets copied) into the method.

```
void func()
{
  int x = 3;
  int[] holder = [x];
  add_one(holder);
  // now holder[0] is 4.  x is still 3.
}

// container here is a copy of the reference holder in the calling scope.
// both container and holder point to the same underlying array object
void add_one(int[] container)
{
    container[0]++;
}
```

Here I use an array, but the wrapper can be any object.

Comment: Is it not possible to use java's boxing and unboxing? Aka, use the Object versions of the primitives? I think _that_ would technically be closer to the pass by reference example in C++, though it would have other side effects.

Comment: Integer objects are immutable, so no.

Answer (score 3):

In java method arguments are *pass-by-value*, and can't be changed in the function. You must wrap the int - or any other primitive type - in an Object or an array. Passing an Object or an array as a method argument passes a reference which can be used to modify the object.

Java already has Object based wrappers for primitive types, e.g. [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), but these are immutable by design. Some libraries provide [mutable versions](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html) of these wrappers; you can also create your own:

```
public class MutableInt
{
    private int val;

    public MutableInt(int val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void setValue(int newVal)
    {
        this.val = newVal;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return this.val;
    }
}

void func()
{
    int x = 3;
    MutableInt wrapper = new MutableInt(x);
    add_one(wrapper);
}

void add_one(MutableInt arg)
{
    arg.setValue(arg.getValue() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this.  Java is only pass by value.  Primitives are obvious, but the thing that's passed for objects is a reference, not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the other answers, Java is purely pass by value.  Objects are passed by what some call "value-reference".   Since an object in java is simply a pointer reference, you can think of the "value" as the address where the object lives on the heap.  So when you make a method call, you're copying the "value", aka address, to the method parameter:

```
Object x = new Object();
foo(x);
```

### During object creation

Heap --> allocate Object (5000)

### Variable Declaration

Stack --> allocate local variable (1000)

### Variable Assignment

Stack address 1000 set to 5000 (to point to object instance)

So you can see that there are two separate memory allocations here.  The "value" of the variable is considered to be it's address on the heap.

### Method Call

Stack --> allocate method parameter 8000

Stack address 8000 set to same value as passed parameter 5000

This is why if you reassign an object instance in a method, it does not propagate back to the caller.  You would have changed the heap location at stack location 8000.  And the calling method's stack location 1000 still has the value 5000 (the original object instance).

Think of it like this in C:

```
void method(myobject * obj);
```

You can certainly change fields of "obj", and you can do this locally:

```
obj = new myobject();
```

But the caller will still see the original value it passed.

Java has no analog to the & reference operator.

And there are built in classes which can be used for the your purposes.  AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, etc... are mutable, though you may suffer a performance hit due to synchronization involved.

I would recommend a generic ValueHolder class to account for all situations where you want to simulate pass by reference:

```
public class ValueHolder<T> {
    private T value;
    // getter/setter/constructor
}
```

Comment: Interesting - but can you add a fully worked example modelled on my C++ snippet?

Comment: I don't have time for that sort of thing.  I took a little time to give further explanation of what java does when you allocate a new instance, and when you make a method call.  It's up to you to take it further.  I gave you the basic value holder, so you can finish that class, and pass it as a method argument anywhere you like to change the value it holds.

Answer (score -3):

```
public int getOneMore(int val) {
  return val + 1;
}
```

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score -3):

Java allows copy by reference for objects and copy by vlaue for primitive types (int,float,etc..). This is so by default and is not subject to change. If you need to change the value of an int inside a function, then you can use the class Integer for example

Comment: No, Java is pass by value.  Only one mechanism, according to James Gosling.

Comment: this is just wrong, java references are passed by value, which is to say, pass by value.  Only.  100% of the time.

Comment: Please take a look on [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657). It might be helpful for you.

Comment: Also, Integer is immutable, so it can't be used in this situation.