# Initializing variables as references to existing objects

Tags: java, swing

This seems like a very beginner question, but I don't know the answer.

Suppose you create a new JFrame in Java. With the new frame comes the default content pane. If I declare a variable and initialize it as that frame's content pane, is the variable I initialized a reference to the frame's content pane or does it become its own thing? Example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
```

If I wanted to, for example, change the layout of the content pane, would adjusting `panel` give the same effect as changing `frame.getContentPane()`?

To show exactly what I mean:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Would this create the same result as:

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Will anything that I then do to `panel` then be reflected in `frame` without me having to then say `frame.setContentPane(panel);` at the end?

Comment: "As a convenience `add` and its variants…have been overridden to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary."—[`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. They point to the same object in memory.

Imagine tying two strings to a balloon. You hold one (let's call you `panel`) and you give the other string to a friend (let's call him `frame.getContentPane()`).

Now if you your friend follows his string, finds the balloon, and puts a hat on it (i.e. `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout());`), then when you follow your string, you will find a balloon with a hat!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. An object in the memory can have multiple references, and any change on any of them will be reflected on all of them (since they all are pointing to the same object). See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they refer to the same `Container` object.

In other words, `getContentPane()` returns a reference to the underlying `Container`. Thus whenever you use the reference, the underlying object is used/affected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
```

indeed lets the variable `panel` point to the content pane of the frame. So calling

```
panel.setLayout( new GridLayout() );
```

will affect the layout of the content pane, as `panel` refers to it.

However, a common mistake is to assume that if you do something like

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
//... some more code

JPanel someOtherFancyPanel = ...;
panel = someOtherFancyPanel;
```

that the content pane of the `JFrame` would become `someOtherFancyPanel`. This is of course not the case. The last statement just let the `panel` variable point to `someOtherFancyPanel` and no longer to the content pane of the frame, and leaves the content pane un-altered.