# swapping of objects in java

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have studied that java is pass by reference but when I execute following code the strings are not swapped in main method why?

```
static void swap(String s1, String s2){
    String temp = s1;
    s1=s2;
    s2=temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Hello", s2 = "world";
    swap(s1, s2);
    System.out.println(s1 + s2);
}
```

Comment: Have a read http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-exchange-objects-java/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You studied wrong sources. Java is pass by value. [Here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) is one source more you can study. And from [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html) you can find discussion about example similar to yours.

Answer (score 8):

**1.** First and foremost thing, `Java` is `pass by Value`.( ie **Pass by Copy**).

**2.** You are **passing the** `reference` **Not** the **Object** to the method.

**Eg:**

```
public class Test{

        private String x;

            public void go(String s){

                this.x = s;

           }

         public static void main(String[] args){

                  Test t = new Test();

                  String a = new String("Bye");

                  t.go(a);


             }
      }
```

The **above code is not to show how swapping is done, but to make an important point visible.**

- When `go(String s)` method is **called by passing an Argument "a" which is an** `Object reference variable` of type String **to the Parameter "s" which is also an** `Object reference variable` of type String, **its just the reference that is passed by Value / Copy.**
- Any **changes done on the** `reference` **will effect the String object on the Heap, NOT** `the reference`.

Comment: "Any changes done on the reference will effect the String object on the Heap, NOT the reference" I don't really get this statement. As opposed to what?

Answer (score 3):

What gets passed to a method is a *copy* of the reference of the object. So, no matter how many times you re-assign the references, the original reference will not be affected.

Try this:

```
static void reverse(StringBuilder builder) {
    builder.reverse();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("hello");
    System.out.println(builder);
    reverse(builder);
    System.out.println(builder);
}
```

However, the below method wouldn't make any difference to the original object passed in.

```
static void swap(StringBuilder builder) {
    builder = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java passes references by value; swapping references in the method being called has no effect in the caller. Your strings are immutable, so there is nothing you can do to them in the `swap` method that would be visible to the caller.

If you pass mutable objects, however, you will see that changes to them made in the `swap` would reflect in the original:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a[] = {"hello", "world"};
    swap(a);
    System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1]);
}
static void swap(String[] a) {
    String t = a[0];
    a[0] = a[1];
    a[1] = t;
}
```

This works, because array is *mutable* (i.e. changes can be made to its state), and because a reference to the original object is passed to the function being called (by value). When `swap` modifies the content of its `a`, the content of `a` in the caller gets modified too, because it is the same object.

Comment: "If you pass mutable objects, however..." It has nothing to do with immutable or mutable objects. You can't swap references to mutable objects either. You're passing a mutable collection and asking to swap the internal elements of it, which is completely different.

Comment: @newacct If you read the entire sentence, not just the beginning, you will see that it does not mention anything about swapping references of mutable objects: it says that changes to mutable objects are reflected in the originals, even though the references are passed by value.

Comment: Okay but I also don't like this sentence: "Your strings are immutable, so swapping references to them has no effect." Swapping references to anything has no effect, and it's not because they are immutable.

Comment: @newacct I can see how that could be misleading. I edited the answer to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Java always passes the references by value. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657) for more details. However, you can swap two strings via arrays or wrapper classes.

---

**EDIT:**

@dasblinkenlight shows how to use arrays to swap two strings, and here is an example of using wrapper class:

```
public class WrapperString
{
    public String text;

    public WrapperString(String text){this.text = text}

    @Override
    public String toString(){return text;}
}
```

```
public static void swap(WrapperString a, WrapperString b)
{
    String temp = a.text;
    a.text = b.text;
    b.text = temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WrapperString s1 = new WrapperString("Hello");
    WrapperString s2 = new WrapperString("World");

    swap(s1, s2);
    System.out.println(s1.text + s2.text);
    // or System.out.println(s1 + s2); since we've already overridden toString()
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
WorldHello
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is Strictly Pass by value.

Let's modify your code as below from the explanation point of view

```
static void swap(String str1, String str2){
String temp = str1;
str1=str2;
str2=temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
String s1 = "Hello", s2 = "world";
swap(s1, s2);
System.out.println(s1 + s2);
```

}

S1 and S2 are the references which hold the address of the string object. For ex: S1=123 , S2= 234

When we call swap method, copy of S1 and S2 is created and will be assigned to str1 and str2.

Which will be str1=123 and str2=234.

Swap method will only swap the values present in str1 and str2. (str1=234 str2=123) whereas S1 and S2 still points to the same memory location.

This is the reason why the swap is not reflected in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void swap(SwapDate[] t)
    {
     SwapDate temp;;
      temp=t[0];
       t[0]=t[1];
       t[1]=temp;
    }




       public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

          SwapDate t[]=new SwapDate[5];
           t[0]=new SwapDate(20,8,2015);
           t[1]=new SwapDate(8,8,2015);

           System.out.println("(First object)Account Opnening date :"+" "+t[0].date);
           System.out.println("(second object)Account Opnening date :"+" "+t[1].date);


           swap(t);
           System.out.println("After Swap");

           System.out.println("(First object)Account Opnening date :"+" "+t[0].date);
           System.out.println("(second object)Account Opnening date :"+" "+t[1].date);


           }
```

Comment: consider adding some explanations.

Answer (score -2):

We can swap objects. It's so simple.Just have to use one dummy object to swap two objects.

Example is given below:

```
    Employee e1=new Employee();
    Employee e2=new Employee();
    e1.setName("e1");
    e2.setName("e2");   
    System.out.println(e1);
    System.out.println(e2);
    Employee temp= new Employee();
    temp=e1;
    e1=e2;
    e2=temp;
```

Comment: Swapping is not the point of the question, "pass by reference" is. Please delete your answer.