# Returning type Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, .net

Java and C# return type of methods are by reference or value? It's really confusing for me, need some explanation.

Thank you all.

Comment: This question has not nearly enough information.

Comment: See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657

Answer (score 2):

In Java *everything* is returned by value. That includes references and here's where the confusion is!

If I have:

```
Trade t = new Trade();
```

then `t` is a *reference* (we'd say it **is-a** Trade, but that refers to the type. `t` really is a reference). When I return that from a method, I'm returning the reference, by value. The reference still points to that original object.

Hence if I return that `t` from a method and then invoke a further method on it, it invokes the method on the `Trade` that it originally pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

C# can return results by either value or reference - it depends how you define the method.

Java can only ever return by value (or strictly speaking, return reference by value.)

Answer (score 1):

As this little Memory Slogan goes in HeadFirst Book..

```
Roses are Red,
This poem is Choppy,
Passing By Value is
Passing By Copy.
```

In `Java` its always **Value that is passed or returned.**

Where as in `C#` it can **return either by Reference or by Copy.**

Comment: Someone's poetic license should be revoked ...