# Passing Arguments

Tags: java, methods, parameters, arguments, return

I'm trying to understand passing arguments and I've run into an issue.

Let's say I have the following code:

I pass the value 60 to the method someMethod. From there I want that value to be modified with a user input. Once it gets modified, I want it pass that value to another method called getValue. The getValue method then returns that value.

Here's the problem:

1) If I were to call someMethod, it would also call for the user input again which I don't want.

2) What is the correct way of printing out the value of the getValue method as doing:

> **New.getValue(int returnedValue);** calls the error "unexpected type,  required value, found class"

```
public class New {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)

private int static num1 = 60;
someMethod(num1);

    public static int someMethod(int myValue)
    {
        //modify the integer
        System.out.println("Enter in the value to modify");
        myValue = sc.nextInt();
        //output the value to a getter method
        getValue(myValue);
        return myValue;
    }

    public static int getValue(int returnedValue)
    {
        return returnedValue;
    }

}
```

As always, if you need clarification, ask! Thanks.

Comment: You use this statement -- `getValue(myValue);` -- but it returns a value which you do not assign to anything, so the value is "thrown on the floor".

Comment: Please take a look at this answer for more clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`someMethod(num1);` should be wrapped inside your `main` method or some other method.

Second: You don't have `sc` variable defined. So, your code fails there also.

Third: You didn't define type of `num1`. It should be `private static int num1 - 60;`

You need to pass real value instead of definition while invoking `getValue()` method.

Example: `System.out.println(getValue(50));`

Comment: I still get the same error when I wrap the passing argument of someMethod inside the someMethod method. When I call it from another static method I say System.out.println(getValue(int returnedValue)); and I get the expected value, got class error.

Comment: You should call something like System.out.println(getValue(50)) You need to pass real value here, not definition

Comment: If I pass in a real value, how will what the user entered get displayed?

Comment: What ever user enters that will be real value.

Comment: Now it makes sense. The value was getting returned without having a place to get stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

**I have also added the modification Part....**

```
public class New {

private static int num1;


    public static int someMethod()
    {

        System.out.println("Enter in the value to modify");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int temp = s.nextInt();

        return getValue(num1+temp); // Modification Done
    }

    public static int getValue(int returnedValue)
    {
        return returnedValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        New.num1 = scan.nextInt();
        int i = someMethod();
        System.out.println(i);



    }

}
```