# Parameter is passed by reference instead of value

Tags: java, android, parameters

I'm using AsyncTask to fetch information from a website for a small learning project I'm doing. I've tried my code, and it "tries" do to what I intend it to do, though I have a small problem.

I'm passing a String as parameter to execute in AsyncTask, but the parameter is referenced by address instead of value. Why is this, and how do I pass a parameter between the UI thread and the background thread properly?

This is my code where the parameter is passed:

```
ibSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Editable artnrInput = input.getText();
            String artnr = artnrInput.toString();
            new Connection().execute(artnr);
        }
    });
```

I've debugged it so far and the parameter "artnr" is a value here.

This is part of my AsyncTask where the error occurs:

```
public class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... artnr)  {
        String url = "http://mobil.systembolaget.se/SokDryck/SokDryck.aspx?artnr="+ artnr + "&lan=01";
```

What I want my String url to look like is this for example:
http://mobil.systembolaget.se/SokDryck/SokDryck.aspx?artnr=221101&lan=01

What it does like when I debug it, making it not work is this:

```
 http://mobil.systembolaget.se/SokDryck/SokDryck.aspx?artnr=[Ljava.lang.String;@43e4c9f8&lan=01
```

I have tried a simple toString(), but it was more of a guess. Why is it not passed as a value, but a reference?

Thank you,
Z

Comment: The reference to the string is passed by value. Objects are not passed at all in Java, let alone by value or by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `artnr[0]` (which is the only parameter you are passing) instead of `artnr` (since `String... artnr` is an array of String objects not a single String object):

```
String url = "http://mobil.systembolaget.se/SokDryck/SokDryck.aspx?artnr="+ artnr[0] + "&lan=01";
```

---

Aside to that, see [How Java passes objects as arguments by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404625/java-pass-by-reference/9404727#9404727)

Answer (score 1):

`String... artnr` is a `var-args`, and is actually an array only. When you print `artnr`, you are printing value of your array reference.

You need to change your `url` string to print `artnr[0]` instead of `artnr` to print the string: -

```
String url = "http://mobil.systembolaget.se/SokDryck/SokDryck.aspx?artnr=" + 
             artnr[0] + "&lan=01";
```

Comment: @Zyril.  It's useful to know that Java passes *everything* by value.  "Reference" is a bad word when talking about objects since they are more accurately pointers.  An object "passed" to a method (which cannot be done) is actually passing the value of a pointer.  That value is a copy of the actual pointer, which is easy to demonstrate by "passing" an object to a Java method then trying to change that object.  You can modify it's properties but you cannot change the object.  EDIT I just spotted the link in Eng.Fouads answer which is a great explanation of this.

Comment: @Simon.. Breathe man breathe. Actually you are right. Edited answer. :)

Comment: No worries actually I was pinging Zyril, it wasn't a comment on your answer which I think is fine. I'm wiser than to tangle with a 15.6K ;)

Comment: @Simon.. haha :) No, it's not that you cannot tangle with a 15.6K. Of course people are not judged by their reps on SO. Everyone can be wrong. And actually, I wasn't offended at all by your comment. So no worries. Cheers :)