# Behavior of class references in Java

Tags: java, class, object, reference

From what I have learned, the class objects in Java are actually references to those objects. An object itself cannot have a variable, only a reference to it.

Consider the following C++ example :

```
SomeClass A(5);
SomeClass &B = A;
SomeClass &C = B;
```

Now, I think I'm right in saying that all of the three statements below will use the exact same object :

```
A.someMethod(); //some object
B.someMethod(); //the same object
C.someMethod(); //the same object
```

However, in Java, although objects are actually references, using the assignment operator will create an entirely new object with a new reference to it.

```
SomeClass A = new SomeClass();
SomeClass B;
B = A;
```

Now, the method calls will call from entirely different objects :

```
A.someMethod(); //uses one object
B.someMethod(); //uses entirely different object
```

Please tell me whether I am right or wrong.

Comment: You are wrong..

Comment: Do you realize how easy this would have been to test & find out for yourself?

Comment: A reference is not an object.  A reference is (don't tell anyone!) a pointer to an object.

Comment: @Matt +1. Bizarre really, given how much care was put into the question (well formatted and articulated).  Would have been [so easy to test](http://ideone.com/KSlNvI).

Comment: For an instant I thought I was looking at C++ code when you say it will create an entirely new object... I'm getting rusty with my C++ knowledge... :(

Comment: Uh... I'll just ask one more thing : This is true for immutable objects right?

Comment: No it is not true, not even for Strings.

Comment: @Vikram: It's true (that you're wrong) for any object, but what do you think an immutable object is?  That's not a language construct in Java.

Comment: Yep, the Java language doesn't really understand "immutable" -- that's just an implementation detail of some classes, and it does not affect how the language processes objects.

Comment: @Vikram This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References are different from objects. A particular object can have more than one reference pointing to it. When calling a method of a class at compile time always the class reference is checked whether the reference type contains the method defined in its class. If not a compile time error is issued. If the method is overridden in a subclass of the given class then the overridden method is called at run-time. At compile time always 'class-ref' in `<class-ref>.method()` is checked to see whether it contains the method definition. Other modifiers like static, final, abstract, method visibility are also checked at compile time itself and a compile time error is issued if the wrong combination of method modifiers is used.

```
    SomeClass A = new SomeClass();
    SomeClass B;
    B = A;        // Same class, same object, different reference


A.someMethod(); //uses one object
B.someMethod(); //uses the same object
```

Comment: +1 for correcting the comments in the example from the OP

Answer (score 2):

Java references are very similar to C++ references. Assigning one reference to another does *not* create a new object. In Java, new objects are created only when you explicitly use the `new` operator.

**Addendum:**

For completeness, I should mention that String objects follow their own rules. In particular, a String constant creates an object at compile time without an explicit use of `new`. Also, auto-(un)boxing, is a more advanced topic where objects are created without explicitly using `new`. However, the main point in both cases remains: assigning one reference to another does *not* create a new object. Both references refer to the same object.

Comment: A String constant will *never* create a new object.  The String object that represents the string literal at runtime is created an interned BEFORE the code executes.  By contrast, unboxing *may* cause objects to be created when the code is run ... but it doesn't always.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to qualify my statement that objects are only created using `new` because some language Nazi would come along and tell me that literal String objects aren't created that way. I hope my updated answer is more accurate.

Comment: "For completeness" - you should also mention that objects in Java can be created reflectively or by object deserialization, neither of which involve the `new` operator.

Comment: In fact, a better way to say what you are trying to say is to simply state that in Java neither a variable declaration or an assignment creates a new object.  (On the other hand, assignment of a C++ reference / pointer typically doesn't create an object either.  It possibly *could* create a new object, but only if you've done something a bit strange with operator overloading.)

Answer (score -2):

Bro actually it seems that java is creating entirely different and new object when you make same references to an object (A=B). But in reality java will provide a copy of object to another reference which you have make like in your example A and B are referring to same object but they have their own copies of that object of type SomeClass. It is same as call by value  thing of C language. You can use and modify that object, but modification made in that object will not effect original copy or other copy, means if you modify SomeClass object using reference B it will not affect object of reference B, although both are referring to same objects but they have their own copies.

Comment: -1 This is incorrect. Both references will point to the same object after an assignment. The object is not copied.