# Passing by reference in Java. Help me understand

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String word = "Super";

reverseString(word);

System.out.println(word);

}

public static String reverseString(String word) {

String helper = "";

int i = word.length() - 1;

while (i >= 0) {
    helper += word.charAt(i);
    i--;

}

return helper;
```

I do not understand why when I'm printing the "word" variable it still prints "Super" even though I changed it in the reverseString method. I understand that strings are passed by reference and not a copy like primitive values.

If I do `word = reverseString(word)` it prints the reverse what I expect, "repuS"

Thanks

Comment: String is immutable in java

Comment: Possible duplicate of which might help you to under the logic behind Pass by reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404625/java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing the string in `reverseString`, you're creating a new one and returning the new one (which you've called `helper`).

A second thing to note about strings in Java is that they're immutable - all string methods return a new string rather than modifying the one you're calling the method on.