# Linked List - remove duplicates algorithm in C#/Java

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I am studying Data Structures and Algorithms in C#/Java. After encountering a solution to the problem of Linked List duplicate removal, I have been struggling to understand it.

The solution is the one proposed by the renowned book *Cracking the coding Interview* (5th edition, page 208).

```cs
void RemoveDuplicates_HashSet(Node n)
{
    HashSet<object> set = new HashSet<object>();

    Node previous = null;
    while (n != null)
    {
        if (set.Contains(n.Data))       // Condition 1
            previous.Next = n.Next;
        else                            // Condition 2
        {
            set.Add(n.Data);
            previous = n;
        }
            
        n = n.Next;
    }
}
```

Running the code with the following linked list `A->B->A->B`:

```
// Creating test Singly LinkedList
Node n = new Node("A");
n.Next = new Node("B");
n.Next.Next = new Node("A");
n.Next.Next.Next = new Node("B");

RemoveDuplicates_HashSet(n);
```

Works perfectly fine: the value of `n` after the method is `A->B`.

By following the code with a debugger, I can see that what happens in the method loop is the following:

```
| Pass | HashSet | n          | previous   | Comment                  |
| ---- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- | ------------------------ |
| –    | –       | A->B->A->B | null       |                          |
| 1    | A       | B->A->B    | A->B->A->B | Condition 2 is triggered |
| 2    | A,B     | A->B       | B->A->B    | Condition 2 is triggered |
| 3    | A,B     | B          | B->B       | Condition 1 is triggered |
| 4    | A,B     | null       | B          | Condition 1 is triggered |
```

I fail to understand how this actually results in several ways:

1. Where/how exactly are duplicates dropped from `n`? I understand that HashSet contains only unique elements, and it will therefore detect if an element was encountered already, however I still cannot see how the algorithm works in its entirety.
2. How is it that the values pointed to by `n` are updated to be `A->B`? Where is it that, given that essentially the loop is simply iterating over the Linked List doing `n = n.Next`, `n` is actually updated with the final value `A->B`? I understand that the list is passed by reference, but I cannot see how it is actually modified.

Comment: This code: `if (set.Contains(n.Data)) previous.Next = n.Next` checks if the element has already been encountered and, if it has, removes `n` from the linked list. It removes the node by assigning `n.Next` to `previous.Next` (which means `previous.Next` no longer points to `n`).

Comment: @Slaw thanks, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. You made me realize that, actually, `previous` and `n` point to the same list (I was mistakenly thinking that they were a "copy" of the same list). Therefore, modifying `previous` means to also modify the original list `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Slaw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681472/linked-list-remove-duplicates-algorithm-in-c-java/65681588?noredirect=1#comment116128502_65681472) pointed me in what I believe to be the right direction.

- Key to question 2) - how the change is actually propagated from the method to the original list - was to understand that [C#/Java objects are passed by reference, but the reference itself is passed by value: while the object can be modified by the method, the reference cannot be modified.](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2731935&seqNum=18#articleText:%7E:text=Objects%20are%20not%20passed%20to%20methods%3B,to%20refer%20to%20a%20new%20object.)
  Once the method ends (termination of the method context), the `n` pointer will point again to the start of the Linked List. Continuously advancing the `n` pointer within the method (by doing `n = n.Next`) does not affect the "external pointer" (the original `n` reference outside of the method).
- As per question 1) - the inner mechanism of the algorithm - the key is to understand that the modifying `previous.Next` does indeed modify the list pointed to by `n`. Quoting [@Slaw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681472/linked-list-remove-duplicates-algorithm-in-c-java/65681588?noredirect=1#comment116128502_65681472):

> This code: `if (set.Contains(n.Data)) previous.Next = n.Next` checks if the element has already been encountered and, if it has, removes n from the linked list. **It removes the node by assigning n.Next to previous.Next (which means previous.Next no longer points to n).**

I've therefore tried to exhaustively diagram what happens in the algorithm.

[image: Diagram of the algorithm.]

Answer (score 2):

> Where/how exactly are duplicates dropped from n?

A property of a Set if, that it may not contain duplicate elements.

```
if (set.Contains(n.Data))
            previous.Next = n.Next;
else
{
            set.Add(n.Data);
            previous = n;
}
n = n.Next;
```

Here you first check, if the data of the current node `n` is contained in the set. If yes, the successor of the previous node is the next node of the current node `n`.
So:

```
[previous]->[n]->[next]
[previous]->[next]
```

Otherwise, the data is added to the set, and you proceed with the next node.

> How is it that the values pointed to by n are updated to be A->B? Where is it that, given that essentially the loop is simply iterating over the Linked List doing n = n.Next, n is actually updated with the final value A->B?

I really don't understand this question. Do you mean "Why is the list modified?"
If yes, then because it is passed (a bit [simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/13912132) ) by reference. So you just dont do a copy, like with primitve types (int,long, ...), but you modify the object itself.

Comment: > `Do you mean "Why is the list modified?"`
yes, and I do understand pass-by-reference to an extent, but apparently I'm still missing something – where is it here that `n` is modified in the first place?

Comment: It is the same as with the list itself. You change the value of some field of the Node and this will show in the list.